# MongoDB and ReactJS aggregation : how to return the count of items?

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, aggregate

Despite looking at many other posts I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong. I want to do a simple "count and group by", so I found out I need to use `collection.aggregate...`.

Here is my `[pubkey].ts` where I execute the aggregation, basically I want to count each entry grouped by `address` sp I'd get something like :

```
{address1: 6},
{address2: 1},
...
```

```
import { connect } from '../../../utils/db'
import Raffles from '../../../utils/db/raffle'

export default async function handler(req, res) {
    const { method } = req
    const { pubkey } = req.query
    await connect()
    switch (method) {
        case 'POST':
          ...
          break
        case 'GET':
            try{
                const ticket = await Raffles.aggregate([{
                    "$match": {
                        "address": pubkey
                    }
                },{
                    "$count": { $sum: 1}
                }])

                res.status(201).json({ success: true, data: ticket })
            } catch (error){
                res.status(400).json({ success: false, data: error })
            }
            break
        default:
          res.status(400).json({ success: false })
          break
      }
}
```

I can't figure out how to do the summing part, if I replace `"$count": "xxyz"` I get a success but right now with `"$count" : {$sum: 1}` I get an error

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use the [$count](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/count/) stage, it only receives a string parameter for the name of the field, so your pipeline could be like this:

```
[
  {
    "$match": {
      "address": pubkey
    }
  },
  {
    "$count": "total"
  }
]
```

It filters the documents that match the address and then gets the count. If you want the count of documents grouped by address, you can use this $group stage in the pipeline (in this case [$count](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/count-accumulator/#mongodb-group-grp.-count) is an aggregation accumulator, so it doesn't take any parameter):

```
[
  {
    $group: {
      "_id": "$address",
      "total": {
        $count: {}
      }
    }
  }
]
```

That should give you some results like this:

```
{_id: address1, total: 6}
{_id: address2, total: 1}
```